divide the total count of the column with individual count in power bi
Need an help in power bi Dax
calculate the total count of category value for the last 12 month, and then divide the total count by individual category count for the last 12 month.

I tried to sum the individual count using
totalcount = sumx(VALUES(Sheet1[category]),Sheet1[categorycount])  

and divide it with
categorycount = calculate(COUNTROWS(Sheet1),FILTER(Sheet1,DATESINPERIOD(Sheet1[Date],SELECTEDVALUE(date1[EOD]),-12,MONTH)))

but i am getting an answer of 1.
